# Focus on element selected in previous page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Suppose I clicked on an element on site and click on navigate to next page. What I want now is - If I click on the previous button and go back to previous page, it should focus and scroll to same element I was in.

Comment: One way is to make use of localStorage. For e.g LocalStorage.setItem(..,..) everytime you click on an item and then on the section you want to focus LocalStorage.getItem(..) if condition. More on https://alligator.io/js/introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage/

Comment: hi :) did you [try](http://plnkr.co/edit/K3Mz9nguWGRB2X4S779z) pushing the current url with the element id to window.history before using $location.path?

Comment: @oCcSking Thank you mate. Well i dont know angularjs and i was just trying new stuff and was not aware of this method. Will try that. Thank you :)